# How to transform a PDDL to search?

Tags: comparison, search, planning, pddl

I have a question about search and planning:
I still haven't understood the difference from the two, but they seem very similar to me; here is a question I am struggling with:

> "Having formulated a PDDL problem, transform it into research,
>   emphasizing what the differences are."

Someone can do an example?

I attached an example of simple PDDL from my book (I'm using  Russell & Norvig)
[image]

Comment: This is an old question, but could you please clarify where you took that slide from? Which section/page of the mentioned book were you reading at the time?

Answer (score 2):

Not all search is planning (is A connected to B), but all planning is search (**how** do I get from this to that).

[Here's an example in Prolog](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/A*%20Planning.swinb) with a domain described in terms of actions, when they are possible, and what the result of the actions are. The description is of an uncomputed graph of un-calculated size where each node is a situation and each edge is an action. Then we have A* search algorithm that searches this graph, calculating it as it goes, to find a plan to reach the goal state. Running the final query will produce a plan via search.